# Files copied from memory card to hard drive via Android not visible on PC

Tags: hard-drive, usb, android

In order to back up my photos while travelling without a laptop I found this approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld9Ms9o4Nmo

in summary is to connect a USB hub adapter to your phone (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0756Q94HV/) and then connect an external hard drive via USB and put the memory card into the hub adapter. Then using X-plore Android app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en_GB) it is possible top copy and paste from the memory card to hard drive.

I tested this before I left and it seemed to work fine. Having copied photos while I was travelling, I can't see them on my PC other than using recovery software.

If I reconnect the hard drive to my phone using the hub adapter I can see the photos on the hard drive without issue.

My question is, why is this happening? Is there some file system issue? Is this just a co-incidental issue or is there something more fundamental. I want to understand before I rely on it again. I didn't have to delete the memory card so I haven't lost anything.

Comment: apparently you have incompatible file system between your phone and PC. Drives formatted under Linux are not readable under Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a filesystem issue.

Run [chkdsk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) from Windows command prompt

Or

right-click on the drive

select Properties click on Tools tab

under Error-checking, click on the Check button

This option will check the drive for file system errors.
Hope it helps

Comment: I'm sure I did that before but checked again and no errors found. On my PC I can see 18GB is used but only a few small folders with Android data files are visible. When I connect the HDD to my phone I can see the missing photos in a folder called found.000

Comment: Make sure view hidden items option is enabled in file explorer to see folders like found.000 .You can try these steps to recover files from such type of folders :https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/recover-files-from-found000-folder.html

Comment: On my PC I have set hidden files to be shown but still can't see them. However if I type the folder in the address bar I can see them.